# Laravel custom color

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I would like to define some custom color in Laravel 6 but don't work.
My target is to add #dee2e6 color and called it custom-blue for whatever,
I try to add in 3 places and define it as a color and class.  Only able to define
it as as a class.  Here are my code.

_variables.scss

```
// Body
$body-bg: #f8fafc;

// Typography
$font-family-sans-serif: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 0.9rem;
$line-height-base: 1.6;

// Colors
$blue: #3490dc;
$indigo: #6574cd;
$purple: #9561e2;
$pink: #f66d9b;
$red: #e3342f;
$orange: #f0b274;
$yellow: #ffed4a;
$green: #38c172;
$teal: #4dc0b5;
$cyan: #6cb2eb;
$brand-primary: #0040c0;
$lwcpa-blue: #cddde1; // custom color
```

app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';


// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

$custom-blue: #cddde1;

.customcss{
    color: #cddde1;
}
```

After  " npm run dev " only one "#cddde1" in the public/css/app.css

public/css/app.css (last few lines)

```
  .table .thead-dark th {
    color: inherit;
    border-color: #dee2e6;
  }
}

.customcss {
  color: #cddde1;
}
```

I try to search "#cddde1" in the public/css/app.css, only fine 1 entry, but I expect 3 entries.
Appreciated if anybody points out what is wrong. Thank you!

Laravel 6,
boostrap 4.5.2

Comment: Output is as expected. Out of the 3 times you have defined twice as variable  - variables don't get included as value by itself in compiled css

Comment: Thanks Dankarnash, I delete one entry, still unable to get "lwcpa-blue" defined.  Why ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Having the same problem.

Comment: No, I cannot add customs color to the vue table.